# Random but not repeating sampling between two dataframes

Tags: r, random, sample

I have two dataframes:

**DF1:**

```
    UNIQUE_ID   City
k5WjB6MQa5Cru Skopje
k4Yq5QqXwoL4e Skopje
S9jGzT5qMZLyF Skopje
mhSHSuxic58Sf Skopje
MU7eys8NKXQog Skopje
GUBe1scNsXQog Bitola
S9jGzT5qMZLyF Kumanovo
```

**DF2:**

```
  ADDRESS                        City  
 РАТКО МИТРОВИЌ 5 БР.29-ДРАЧЕВО Skopje
 УЛ. МЕТОДИЈА ПАТЧЕВ БР.17А     Skopje
 УЛ ДРАЧЕВСКА 123               Skopje
 УЛ.ДОМАЗЕТОВСКА БР. 24         Skopje
 ДРАЧЕВО УЛ. ЈАНКО МИШИЌ БР. 3  Skopje
 УЛ. ПАРТИЗАНСКИ ПАТ 2 БР. 1    Skopje
```

I want to assign a random address for each unique ID in DF1. The assignment should fulfill two criteria:

1. The address should not repeat until all unique addresses from DF2 are used up;
2. The address should be pulled for the respective city.

So the desired output would look like:

**New_DF**

```
    UNIQUE_ID   City   ADRESS
k5WjB6MQa5Cru Skopje   РАТКО МИТРОВИЌ 5 БР.29-ДРАЧЕВО
k4Yq5QqXwoL4e Skopje   УЛ. МЕТОДИЈА ПАТЧЕВ БР.17А
S9jGzT5qMZLyF Skopje   УЛ ДРАЧЕВСКА 123
mhSHSuxic58Sf Skopje   УЛ.ДОМАЗЕТОВСКА БР. 24
MU7eys8NKXQog Skopje   ДРАЧЕВО УЛ. ЈАНКО МИШИЌ БР. 3
GUBe1scNsXQog Bitola   NA
S9jGzT5qMZLyF Kumanovo NA
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
    DF1 (dput)
dput(sk[, c(2, 3)])
structure(list(City = structure(c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Bitola", 
"Gevgelija", "Gostivar", "Kavadarci", "Kicevo", "Kocani", "Krusevo", 
"Kumanovo", "Negotino", "Ohrid", "Prilep", "Skopje", "Stip", 
"Struga", "Strumica", "Tetovo", "Vinica"), class = "factor"), 
    unique_id = 1:5), .Names = c("City", "unique_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L))

DF2 (dput)

dput(head(sk2))
structure(list(ADDRESS = c("РАТКО МИТРОВИЌ 5 БР.29-ДРАЧЕВО", 
"УЛ. МЕТОДИЈА ПАТЧЕВ БР.17А", "УЛ ДРАЧЕВСКА 123", "УЛ.ДОМАЗЕТОВСКА БР. 24", 
"ДРАЧЕВО УЛ. ЈАНКО МИШИЌ БР. 3", "УЛ. ПАРТИЗАНСКИ ПАТ 2 БР. 1"
), City = c("Skopje", "Skopje", "Skopje", "Skopje", "Skopje", 
"Skopje")), .Names = c("ADDRESS", "City"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "City", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    City = "Skopje"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "City", drop = TRUE, .Names = "City"))
```

Comment: Could you `dput` to provide samples of both the data frames? I just had some encoding issues putting them on my machine & would like to make sure I don't introduce another issue when I try this.

Comment: @mysteRious just updated the OP with dput.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded in your DF1 and DF2 and then created a new data frame like this:

```
> library(dplyr)
> matched.df <- DF1 %>% mutate(address=DF2[sample(nrow(DF1)),]$ADDRESS)
```

The new data frame has all the right columns, but looks funny when you try to display it:

```
> names(matched.df)
[1] "City"      "unique_id" "address"
```

But the addresses themselves look OK when you look them up:

```
> matched.df$address[1]
[1] "УЛ.ДОМАЗЕТОВСКА БР. 24"
```

Comment: Yes, but it's only working when the two cities are the same. Otherwise, it's mixing addresses between two cities. I need to sample a random address from the city where the Unique_ID is located.

Comment: For example, if an UNIQUE_ID has as a City - New York, then the sample should be done from the New York addresses in DF2.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with

```
df1 <- c('k5WjB6MQa5Cru', 'Skopje',
'k4Yq5QqXwoL4e', 'Skopje',
'S9jGzT5qMZLyF', 'Skopje',
'mhSHSuxic58Sf', 'Skopje',
'MU7eys8NKXQog', 'Skopje',
'GUBe1scNsXQog', 'Bitola',
'S9jGzT5qMZLyF', 'Kumanovo')
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(df1, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df1) <- c("UNIQUE_ID", "City")


df2 <- c('РАТКО МИТРОВИЌ 5 БР.29-ДРАЧЕВО', 'Skopje',
'УЛ. МЕТОДИЈА ПАТЧЕВ БР.17А', 'Skopje',
'УЛ ДРАЧЕВСКА 123',            'Skopje',
'УЛ.ДОМАЗЕТОВСКА БР. 24'  ,   'Skopje',
'ДРАЧЕВО УЛ. ЈАНКО МИШИЌ БР. 3' , 'Skopje',
'УЛ. ПАРТИЗАНСКИ ПАТ 2 БР. 1'   , 'Skopje')
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(df2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df2) <- c("ADDRESS", "City")



unique.cities <- unique(df1$City)
df1$Address <- unlist(sapply(unique.cities, function(x){
  n.ids <- nrow(df1[df1$City == x, ])
  new.address <- rep(df2[df2$City == x, ]$ADDRESS, ceiling(n.ids/nrow(df2[df2$City == x, ])))
  new.address[1:n.ids]
}))
```

I hope this helps!